# How to do content search for multiple pdf files using lucene in java

Tags: java, search, pdf, lucene

with the reference of the following link i can able to search the contents of only single pdf file, but my requirement is to search multiple pdf files content please suggest me how to do that.

[Simple word search in PDF](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/11/simple-word-search-in-pdf-files-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

The example provided create objects ready to index using this:

```
File pdfFile = new File("src/resources/SamplePDF.pdf");
IndexItem pdfIndexItem = index(pdfFile);
```

And, once it has created an `Indexer`, adds them to the index with:

```
indexer.index(pdfIndexItem);
```

I would suppose you can follow the same pattern for additional files.

Comment: thanks for the reply i tried by giving folder name in place of file name it is not accepting and i also tried to call every file in the folder in a for loop it is also not working can u please suggest me....

Comment: The first approach listed doesn't work because it doesn't traverse files recursively.  You'dd nee to call it for each independantly.  Doing it in a loop probably doesn't work because you aren't keeping a new IndexItem around for each iteration to be then indexed with the `indexer.index` call, at a guess.  Just a shot in the dark on that last, without knowing exactly what you tried.